# Share program files between multiple "Process Flow"

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have multiple "Process Flows".
I have multiple program files.
I would like to use each program file in each "Process Flow".
I would like to sequence the use of the program files differently in each "Process Flow".

What is the canonical way to do this in SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is with Ordered Lists.
A seven minute demonstration video is [here](https://video.sas.com/detail/video/3862944642001/organize-a-project-and-use-multiple-process-flows).

In words:
You should create an ordered list for each sequence of tasks/programs.

**Aside (wet-paint):**

AFAICT, the "Process Flow" is useful for organizing code and tasks where they are unique to each process flow.
If you have shared objects then you should re-purpose the "Process Flow" idiom in the following way:

1. Organize shared program files, etc. into a "Shared tasks" or "Support tasks", etc "Process Flow".
2. Assign single use program files, etc. to a "Process Flow" named to reflect their functionality.
3. Create an "Ordered List" that executes that shared and single use objects in the correct order for that task.  Name the "Ordered List" to reflect the fact that it is the object to be Executed, e.g. "Monthly Run: Overdue Balances" and "Daily Run: Overdue Balances".